# Can Path.Data creation be simplified in code?

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp, rectangles, pathgeometry

I have a Canvas in UWP, and need to draw Path on it in code-behind.  I have it working, but it seems needlessly verbose, especially considering that I need to have four instances of it in a switch-case statement.  I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify the code, or at least to consolidate it into a single line:

**C#**

```
Rect door = new Rect(left, top, width, height);
RectangleGeometry doorGeometry = new RectangleGeometry();
doorGeometry.Rect = door;
doorGroup.Children.Add(doorGeometry);
path.Data = doorGroup;
```

I tried putting it into a single line as below, but received several "No constructor with 1 elements" errors in IntelliSense.  Is there a way to do this that simplifies/lessens the amount of code used?

```
GeometryGroup doorGroup = new GeometryGroup(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(left, top, width, height);
```

Comment: There's no other way to set the `Path.Data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write it in a simpler manner using just the built-in API. What you could do however is to write your own ["builder" pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)-based class that could feature a Fluent API that would allow you to build up the path data "as a single statement".

See [this blog post](http://www.stefanoricciardi.com/2010/04/14/a-fluent-builder-in-c/) as an example of a fluent builder.

Comment: Thanks for the blog post link, that was an interesting post.  What I ended up doing (before seeing your answer)  was to create a function that took in the left, top, width, and height parameters, and returns a GeometryGroup object.  This way duplicate code is minimized, and the `switch` block is kept concise.  I'm not sure in this case that the DoorPath warrants a whole class to itself, as would be needed for the fluent design, but for more important objects I could definitely see the appeal of the fluent design approach.